# After creating a project on Xcode, i deleted the viewController that comes by default and created a new one. But the project does not run

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I created a project in Xcode and deleted the viewController file that comes by default in it. I added a new file(objective-c class) and added some controls in its viewDidLoad and run the project but it does not seem to work,the view it shows is blank. Is there any setting to be made?

Comment: Is your project using storyboard ?

Comment: No. Everything i have done programmatically.

Comment: Show us something, which you have done >?

Comment: Show us your 'AppDelegate' code then :)

Comment: I haven't added anything in the appDelegate. I have just created a button and a label as of now in the viewDidLoad and added their subView. In the viewController which was provided by default the code works fine but not in the newly added file. There is some setting to be done in the plist i guess(not sure).

Comment: Check my answer if you are using xib for interface builder in your project.

Comment: By default, a single view app will use storyboard. If that's the case, go in storyboard and attach your new class to the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `deleted the viewController file that comes by default in it.`, that means that you have chosen application type other than `Empty Application`.  That means most probably you might have chosen a `Single view Application`, as the defaultViewcontroller file will be provided with SingleView application( means with Storyboards by defaults on Xcode 5+).

So even if you have deleted the application, you can just

- add a NewViewController (subclassed from `UIViewController`),
- name it (`myViewController`)
- save it
- Import it in appDelegate File. (`#import "myViewController.h"`)
- Create an instance of it.(`myViewController *vc = [myViewController alloc]init]`)
- Push it on navigationController

If you want to add buttons or anything else,

- just create objects in `myViewController`
- & instantiate them
- add them to SubViews.

  ---

  **If you are using storyBoards, then**

  - Add a new ViewController file & name it, something like `myViewController`
  - Add a new ViewControlelr object in the mainStoryboard file by drag & drop.
  - Select its inheriting class in the inspector on RHS, as `myViewController`
  - No need to modify anything in `appDelegate` file.
  - Make that controller in storyBoard as entryPoint. A default arrow will be preceding your controller.

    ---

hope that gives you the overview.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer.just the upper triangle where you made it green ticked. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set mainviewcontroller from **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method of  **appdelegate.m** file.

as below

```
#import "Yourviewcontroller.h"
```

and in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method:-

```
    self.viewController = [[YourViewControoler alloc] initWithNibName:@"Your xib file" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes. This works if i have a xib interface builder in my project. But i have storyboard by default in my project. So is there a way out when using storyboard?

Comment: In Storybaord u have to set property "is initial view controller" as checked of View controller.

Comment: If you gt ur answer than appreciate my answer by up voting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have modify the AppDelegate file.

Suppose you add the new controller that name is DashboardViewController.

***DashboardViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DashboardViewController;

@property (nonatomic,strong) DashboardViewController *viewController;


***DashboardViewController.m***



@synthesize viewController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
         self.viewController = [[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:nil];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```